# Deploying same web application on two different servers with different connectionStrings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications, iis-7

I have a web application running on one server.. Can I have the same application working on a second server with the connection Strings pointing to the second server?

Comment: why not. Deploy the same code in second server and update connection string in web.config to the second server.

Comment: I tried the same procedure. Copy Pasted the code in the second server and changed the connection strings in the web.Config to the appropriate server credentials and Hosted it using IIS7. However the Javascript part of the web application was not displayed with only the HTML content being shown on the web browser. Any reason why ?

Comment: In case of purchased JS API, there is authentication part that checks source of origin.. that might cause similar issue, still if you can post link/code of not working page that will help answer better

Comment: It would be really difficult to post the code here. I have a doubt If I try to change the connection string to the login credentials of the second server in the web config file stored in the 1st server , the web application shows data of the second server. However if I copy past the entire project into the second server and try to access the website. Only HTML markup is shown and Javascript and Jquery is blank

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "Publish" option (in solution explorer -> right click on project). It provides you an interface for multipile deploy options where you can specify diffrent connection strings for different publish profiles.